# Save array that can be used throughout the app in swiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I saved some data in an array and that array should be used globally through out the app. That array can be edited or deleted. I have found we can use `@EnvironmentObject` and tried the following

```
@main


struct DineApp: App {
 var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
        View1().environmentObject(BookViewModel())
}
}



BookViewModel :
class BookViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published  var bookarray = [Book]()

func saveBook (Id: Int, Name: String){
           bookarray.append(Book(Id: id, Name: name ). // How to use this bookarray through out the app
}
}

View1: 
struct View1: View {
@EnvironmentObject var bookviewModel : BookViewModel
    var body: some View {
    //Code to save book on a button click
    saveBook(Id: selectedId, Name: selectedName) //Selected books will be saved.  
    }
} 

struct View1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static let bookViewModel = BookViewModel()
 static var previews: some View {
        View1().environmentObject(bookViewModel)
    }
}
    
View4: 
struct View4: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var bookviewModel : BookViewModel
    var body: some View {
        // Display saved books in a list. But it shows empty List
        List(bookviewModel.bookarray) id:\name){row in
                Text(row.name)
        }
    }
}
struct View4_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static let bookViewModel = BookViewModel()
 static var previews: some View {
        View4().environmentObject(bookViewModel)
    }
}
```

This gives me an error that `EnvironmentObject should be passed from ancestor view`. I couldn't understand , where to pass and how to pass. The point is I need to access the bookarray in multiple views, so I couldn't understand whats the point of passing from one view to another.

In `obj-C` we have `appdelegate` and we can store any data in it if we want to use the data globally through out the app . what is the similar in swiftUI?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. There is a gap between `View1` and `View4` things like `sheet` and `NavigationView` can require you to re inject. The error should tell you exactly where you are missing the connection and BTW if you want to use AppDelegate just add it.

Answer (score 1):

> EnvironmentObject should be passed from ancestor view

means that you have to inject the object into the environment on a higher level of the view hierarchy. And the views which want to have access to the object must be descendants of this view.

The top level is the `@main` struct, add it there for example

```
@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .environmentObject(BookViewModel())
    }
}
```

`View4` must be a descendant of `SwiftUIApp` or of `ContentView`

Comment: If I need to store other variables from other viewModels too globally then how can I pass them in @main. Actually Im new to swiftUI, I'm trying to compare obj-C AppDelegate equivalent in swift

Comment: You can call the `.environmentObject` modifier multiple times. And you can get access to the `AppDelegate` class – if there is one – from everywhere with `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate : AppDelegate`

Comment: I tried with ur code and its not working. List shows empty. Also I tried https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/observable-objects-environment-objects-and-published. It doesnt seem to work

Comment: Can u plz look at my code, I edited it

Comment: Again, `View4` must be a descendant of `View1`. An isolated `View` makes no sense anyway. You have to navigate to it via TabView or NavigationLink or by presenting it.